# My CALayer is not appearing

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to get CALayer working so I can start practicing some animations tricks that I would like to learn. At the moment I want to scale and move things along the z-axis.

Right now I see nothing when I run this code. I would expect to see a black square. But instead nothing is appearing. The code compiles (obviously) and there are no warnings. Is there something I am missing?

I've be trying to learn by reading this tutorial

http://watchingapple.com/2008/04/core-animation-3d-perspective/

But obviously there is a hole in my knowledge somewhere thats left me stumped.

-() addAnImageInTheBackground
    {

```
CALayer *theImage = [CALayer layer];

theImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
theImage.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;

CGRect frame;
frame.origin.x = 10;
frame.origin.y = 10;

frame.size.height = 20;
frame.size.width = 20;

theImage.frame = frame;
theImage.bounds = frame;

CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -2000;
theImage.sublayerTransform = transform;
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:-10];

[theImage setValue:value forKeyPath:@"transform.translation.z"];

[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:theImage];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `theImage.bounds = frame` is wrong. You don't want to change the bounds. It's also possible your transform is wrong, but I can't recall enough about transformation matrices to remember what .m34 does ;)

Comment: .m34 is for z-axis transforms. Whats wrong with bounds? Its what i saw in the tutorial. Thanks for the help Kevin

Comment: Either the tutorial is wrong, or you have a transcription error. Setting the frame of a view already sets the bounds size, and you almost never want to change the bounds origin unless you really know what you're doing.